# Unique key constraint violation in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

i am loading data from flat file to table with help of sql* loader in oracle10g.

but while loading it is showing the below error.

*

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SANFORDINTEGRATOR.SUBSCRIBER_ID_PK) violated
ORA-06512: at "SANFORDINTEGRATOR.DATAMOVE", line 26
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How can i resolve it.

thanks in advance

Comment: oh dear... your database wants to tell you, that the ID that you read from the flat file, is already existing in your database... and because it needs to be unique you get a PK violation. So either fix it in the flatfile, or drop the duplicates from your DB first... if you rely on the ids somewhere else this is going to be fun...

Answer (score 2):

The table SANFORDINTEGRATOR has a constraint that requires a column (probably SUBSCRIBER_ID) has unique values (probably because it's the primary key). You're obviously loading data that doesn't have unique values for this column. So Oracle rejects it.

To fix it, make sure the SUBSCRIBER_ID are unique (both accross your file and the already existing data in the table).

Comment: i have primary key for subscrier id column but i have to load flat file data without disabling pk constaring

Comment: I didn't say you should disable the constraint. Does your file contain SUBSCRIBER_IDs at all? If yes, why aren't they unique?

Comment: thank you code for response i solved it becausue client sent wrong file to us